# Mysql - use result of another query inside subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am trying to get the maximum and minimum result of orders per day of a predefined range.

Example
From January 1 to January 30 I got 300 orders. What the number of orders of the highest selling day? And what is the minimum? And the average?

This would be quite simple except that I need this number city based, and the cities belongs to the results of another query.

What I have so far:

```
select count(orderNumber) as total_order_number, 
SUM(cast(REPLACE(total_value, ',', '.') as decimal(8,2))) as total_value, 
avg(cast(REPLACE(total_value, ',', '.') as decimal(8,2))) as average_price,
(count(orderNumber) / 30) as average_order_number,
(select count(*) as total_orders_day from orders where date_created between date('2016-01-01') and date('2016-01-30') group by date(date_created) order by total_orders_day desc limit 1) as max_orders_day,
(select count(*) as total_orders_day from orders where date_created between date('2016-01-01') and date('2016-01-30') group by date(date_created) order by total_orders_day asc limit 1) as min_orders_day,
city
from orders o
where date_created between date('2016-01-01') and date('2016-01-30')
group by o.city
order by total_order_number DESC
limit 7
```

This bring me up results of total_order_number, total_value, average_price, average_order_number per city just ok. But min and max values are the same because I don`t know how to separate results by city.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a simple matter for a subquery:

```
select city, min(numorders), max(numorders), avg(numorders)
from (select city, date(date_created) as dte, count(*) as numorders
      from orders o
      where date_created between date('2016-01-01') and date('2016-01-30')
      group by city, date(date_created)
     ) d
group by city;
```

Comment: This should separate results by city? I need also the original columns. I don`t think I can use this whole as a subquery because it contains more than one column

Comment: @HenriqueM. . . . I missed that part of the query.  Fixed the answer.

Comment: Ok, this way seems to work fine. But another column in my query is "total", which I need the absolute number of orders of that date range. Since we are grouping by date, how can I abstract the amount of the entire range? I tried by just adding a count to numorder but it retrieves the number of the first day the query found instead of the total because of group by statement. Same thing for 'total_value'

Comment: @HenriqueM. . . . It is only possible to answer the questions that are asked.  These are specifically:  "What the number of orders of the highest selling day? And what is the minimum? And the average?"  If you have another question, you should ask it as another question.

Comment: Sorry, it was in my original query